# Проверить открыт ли dropdown Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Как проверить открыт ли `dropdown` `Bootstrap` с помощью `js/jQuery`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно проверить в текущий момент времени по какому-то другому событию, то можно узнать по наличию класса show у dropdown

```js
$('.is-it-open').on('click', function(){
  if($('.dropdown').hasClass('show')){
    console.log('сейчас открыт');
  }else{
    console.log('сейчас закрыт');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="is-it-open">открыт ли?</button>

<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Так же есть события, которые сработают, когда dropdown будет открыт\зкакрыт

```js
$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('open');
});

$('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('close');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline-block;'>
  <button class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle' style='background: gray; border: none; width: 100px; padding: 0px;' type='button' id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' ".$del." style='cursor: pointer;'>Удалить комментарий</a>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Цитировать</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавили понты)

Comment: @doox911 не совсем понял, я добавил вариант, когда нужно не подписаться на открытие\закрытие, а узнать по какому-то другому событию открыт ли он сейчас, это разные вещи, а по вопросу на 100% не понятно, что именно нужно автору

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Лайк поставил)

Comment: Зачем вы убрали вторую кнопку?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин потому, что суть от этого не меняется, только лишний код в сниппете, вернул вторую

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#dd_1').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('Открываем 1-й');
});
$('#dd_1').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('Открыт 1-й');
});
$('#dd_2').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('Открываем 2-й');
});
$('#dd_2').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log('Открыт 2-й');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="dd_1" class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dd_2" class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Читать документацию до конца!](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events)

Comment: Зачем вы убрали вторую кнопку?

Comment: Я ваш пример вообще не брал) На самом деле, проблем и нет, чтобы работало с двумя. Сейчас вставлю вторую.

Comment: У нас неизвестное количество id.

Comment: Добавляете  `data`  (например,`data-id`)  и конкатинируйте.